# MySQL statement to list by numeric variable value ascending

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to order a list by a specific variable called 'wpcf-range' which is numeric and it needs to list ASC. This is for a WordPress website, but the previous developer has used a MySQL statement rather than do it the WordPress way thus confusing my beginner brain. See code below, any help would be most appreciated...

```
$listing = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '" . $term->term_taxonomy_id . "' LIMIT " . $start . ", " . $limit);
```

Comment: `...ORDER BY wpcf-range ASC ...` ?

Comment: thanks for response, how does that fit into the above statement?

Answer (score 0):

If `wpcf-range` is a column in the `wp_posts` table, then you could add an `ORDER BY` clause to the sql query text, before the `LIMIT` clause, e.g.

```
... $term->term_taxonomy_id . "' ORDER BY `wpcf-range` LIMIT " . $start . ...
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(NOTE: it's a bit odd that a column name would have a dash in it, which leads me to suspect that this may not be a column in the `wp_posts` table. If it does include a dash, you need to enclose the reference to the column name in backticks. It needs to be enclosed in backticks, otherwise, MySQL is going to see that dash as a subtraction operator.

If the datatype of `wpcf-range` is a character type rather than a numeric type, then you can cast that to numeric by adding zero to it...

```
ORDER BY `wpcf-range`+0
```

If that's not a name of a column in the table (and we can't tell from the information provided in your question... if that's intended to be a column name or its intended to be an expression... we can't tell if wp_posts contains two numeric columns, named `wpcf` and `range`, such that what you are meaning is to subtract one from the other, and the order the resultset by the resulting value, e.g.

```
ORDER BY `wpcf` - `range`
```

If this isn't unique, you may want to also include other columns in the ORDER BY so that the order of the resultset is deterministic, e.g.

```
ORDER BY `wpcf` - `range`, post_id
```

Comment: thanks, but the ordering did not work. i think maybe there is more than that line of code to edit. see below for more of the code snip...
`$listing = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '" . $term->term_taxonomy_id . "' ORDER BY 'wpcf-range' +0 LIMIT " . $start . ", " . $limit);
$get_found_rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS total");
$total_results = $get_found_rows[0]->total;
$total_pages = ceil($total_results / $limit);`

Comment: The column reference in the ORDER BY clause should be enclosed in backticks, not single quotes.  (I thought that was clear in my answer. The two are not equivalent. The single quotes are used to specify a string literal, so it doesn't matter if that's a column in `wp_posts` table or not. (The information provided in your comment here might better be added as an Update or Addendum to your question. But there's nothing in that code snippet that indicates whether `wpcf-range` is a column, or indicates if that's intended to be an expression (subtracting the value of `range` from `wpcf`), or ...

Comment: wpcf-range is the name of the variable. I use the Types plugin and it always adds wpcf- to the front of variables. So this mean that... 

ORDER BY `wpcf` - `range`

...is the code to use?

Comment: @Amesey: you can only ORDER BY columns from referenced tables, or by expressions. MySQL doesn't know anything about your variables names or any plugins you are using. I don't have any visibility to the columns in your `wp_posts` table. But if you have a column named `range` in the table, and you want to ORDER BY the value stored in that column... then add `ORDER BY range` to the query. Note that `RANGE` is a MySQL reserved word, so the column reference will need to be enclosed in backticks. Also note that if that column is not defined as numeric datatype, you'll want to `ORDER BY range+0` to

Comment: just downloaded the xml file of the post type to get the values...

`<wp:postmeta>
<wp:meta_key>wpcf-range</wp:meta_key>
<wp:meta_value><![CDATA[3315]]></wp:meta_value>
</wp:postmeta>`

does this help identifying the name of the column?

Answer (score 0):

```
$listing = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '" . $term->term_taxonomy_id . "' ORDER BY wpcf-range ASC LIMIT " . $start . ", " . $limit);
```